# Displaying HTML error

Tags: html, asp.net

I know there is something wrong with formatting the code but I'm not sure what is it.

**Not Working :**

```
    <div id="item_list">
    <div id="item">

        <%= LoadItems() %>

  </div>           
  </div>
```

LoadItems should return this :

```
            returnString = "<div style=\"cursor: pointer;\" class=\"item\"    itemid=\"1670\"> " + 
                 "  < div class=\"item_pic\"><img src = \"icons/icon_commerce_anccube_skill.jpg\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 68px; height: 71px;\"></div>" +
            " <div class=\"item_title\"><a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" >< span > Skill Upgrade Pack</span></a></div> " +
             "<div class=\"clear\"></div> "+
             "<div class=\"item_price\"><span style = \"\" > 2,000 gPotatoes</span></div> </div> ";
```

**Working code :**

```
 <div id="item_list">
 <div id="item">
   <div style="cursor: pointer;" class="item" itemid="1670">
   <div class="item_pic"><img src="icons/icon_commerce_anccube_skill.jpg" alt="" style="width: 68px; height: 71px;"></div>
  <div class="item_title"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Skill Upgrade Pack</span></a></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="item_price"><span style="">2,000 gPotatoes</span></div>
  </div>

  </div>           
   </div>
```

Comment: `"LoadItems should return this"` - Well, does it?  What is the difference on the *client-side* between the working a non-working versions?

Comment: I mean that's the ReturnString is returning the not working code ... I copied the working code and added backslashes , shouldn't that do the job ?

Comment: If the problem is happening in the client-side rendering, it might be worth a moment to actually look at the client-side markup.  Pictures of the running application aren't really as useful as actual debugging.

Comment: What's the question? Provide a MVCE if you want help, we have literally no idea what you're trying to do. You have plenty of other questions, you should know how to write good questions by now.

Comment: @tambre `working code' should return same thing as `returnString' but It's not , and It's giving the bad display as you can see in the images. I guess It's pretty clear

Comment: Looks more like a styling/css issue than a asp.net one me. `LoadItems()` will return a string, with or without correct HTML in it.

Comment: @Dablackninja And yet you don't attach that function to your question. We can't help if we can't actually see the code that contains the problem.

Comment: I'm only returning that string in the function , that's all .
I'm only wondering If I formatted the code correctly (Backslashes and quotes etc... ) that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second div has a space between the `<` and `div`. This won't be parsed as a div.

You also have a broken span tag on the third line.

I would imaging this is what is breaking your layout.

If you use single quotes to encapsulate the string rather than doubles you wouldn't need to escape the quotes.

Example:

```
returnString = '<div style="cursor: pointer;" class="item" itemid="1670">' +
               '<div>etc...</div>' +
               '</div>'
```